# Is it possible to upgrade a BGA 1224 CPU?

Tags: cpu, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I want to upgrade the CPU of my T430s laptop from i7-3520M to i7-3632QM.
I'm sure i7-3632QM is supported (same socket (BGA1224), same TDP (35W) and microcode found in BIOS (306A9.PAT)).

So my question is:
1) is it possible to de-solder the current CPU without damaging it, and to solder the new CPU without damaging it and the motherboard ?
2) if so, what tools are necessary? who can do that at a reasonnable cost?

Until now, I was unable to find anyone able (or willing) to do that (I'm located in France, and I have tried a local fablab, electronics shops, TV repair shops, ...). Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible... Yes... But the likelihood of heating a board to remove the [ball grid array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) CPU and placing a new 1224 pin CPU in place, reheating the board to melt the solder balls and getting them all to stick in "dirty" sockets **AND** do all this without damaging or loosening another component? About the same as being struck by lightning while being bitten by shark. BGA was designed not to be upgradable, to be honest if you find a reliable facility willing to do this, it would be so cost prohibitive you could just go buy a new laptop.

Comment: I think you would be disappointed anyways... A quick look through some benchmark comparisons of the two CPUs shows only marginal gains, even with the additional cores of the 3632. http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3632QM-vs-Intel-Core-i7-3520M

Comment: https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i7-3632QM+%40+2.20GHz gives a slightly different picture, but single thread rating are indeed disappointing... So I won't have any regrets :-)